# SQL- query which finds the name of a specific row which has max linked columns from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables:

```
   users: id, name
   albums: id, user_id
```

I need a SQL query which finds the NAME of the user who has the max count of albums. How do I do that?

Here is what I have tried so far -

```
SELECT Users.name 
FROM Users 
JOIN Albums
ON Users.id = Albums.user_id 
HAVING  COUNT(Albums.id) = MAX(COUNT(Albums.id));
```

(this doesnt work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sub query should return the name of the user having maximum number of albums.

```
SELECT name FROM Users WHERE id = (SELECT user_id FROM Albums GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Here is the GROUP BY used to group the user_id with the COUNT of each user_id occurrences otherwise return the count for all records in the table.

If there multiple max occurrences with same count then you have to use IN keyword for the query to return all names and the query will be bit complex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a limit 1

```
select   Users.name, count(distinct Albums.id) max_count
from  Users
INNER JOIN Albums on Users.id = Albums.user_id 
GROUP BY Users.name
ORDER max_count desc limit 1
```

or a filter the having beas on max for max count

```
select   Users.name
from  Users
INNER JOIN Albums on Users.id = Albums.user_id 
GROUP BY Users.name
HAVING count(distinct Albums.id) = (
    select max(t.max_count) from (
    select   Users.name, count(distinct Albums.id) max_count
    from  Users
    INNER JOIN Albums on Users.id = Albums.user_id 
    GROUP BY Users.name
    ) t
)
```

Comment: 2nd option seem not very optimal to me

Comment: In mysql there is limit so is possible reduce the result only at a row ..but in pure sql (not using limit or db dependen row limitation)   the second work for all sql standard db

Comment: I see.But still, I suspect that other DBs have other ways to optimize such type of query

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `join`, `group by`, and `limit`:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM Users u JOIN
     Albums a
     ON u.id = a.user_id
GROUP BY u.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This makes some assumptions:

- Different users do not have the same name.  If so, you should include `u.id` in the `GROUP BY`.
- If there are ties, then you still want one row.